# Recovering Dial up Network password

Tags: networking

I connect using PPPOE to the internet using the username and password my ISP provided.I had it saved in one of my Windows 7 system, now I want to use it on another system running ubuntu 12.04
Is there anyway without contacting the ISP to copy the network configuration? I don't seem to recollect the password while the username is visible. From what I've learnt they are stored encrypted though there maybe some utilities like DialuPass which recovers those passwords. Unfortunately, the downloadable executable of dialupass appears as a mailicous file to the Chrome downloader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialupass from Nirsoft is not malicious, try downloading it again and only from Nirsoft directly - http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dialupass.html

If Chrome says it is bad, ignore - it isn't, Nirsoft make many good programs and some of them are incorrectly detected as malware due to false positives and the way that they work.